# Rails 5 - Apply limit to eagerly loaded children of collection

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, limit, has-many

I need help generating a query that applies a limit to the children of a collection. Here's a simple demonstration of my problem.

Post model

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
end
```

Comment model

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
end
```

I want to display all posts in a view, including up to 3 comments for each post. I currently have this query

```
@posts = Post.includes(:comments)
```

But this of course will fetch all of the comments, instead of only 3 for each. I also thought of this

```
@posts = Post.all
@comments = Comment.where(post_id: @posts.ids).limit(3) #this will not apply the limit for each post
```

I have no idea how to do this without causing an N+1 query.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**UPDATE**

I think I may need to clarify my expected results. I want to execute an activerecord query on posts that will eagerly load three comments for EACH post. so that I get:

3 comments for post with id 1
3 comments for post with id 2
and so on. Is this possible without causing an N+1 query? the simplest but undesired solution would be this:

```
@posts.each {|post| post.comments.limit(3)}
```

This would give me my desired results, but would execute a query for each post.

**UPDATE**
The accepted answer allows you to apply any sort of query conditions to the association, but this conditions are ignored when using `includes`. This means that I would still be loading all comments to memory, wasting memory resources. I'd prefer another solution, but there seems to be no way to achieve a perfect solution here.

Comment: as per my understanding, if you eager load comments , it won't cause n + 1 query . please check in your console this code `@posts = Post.includes(:comments).all ` `@posts.each do |post| post.comments.limit(3) end` .

Comment: @Vishal you are right, and that might work for me at the moment. My problem with using includes in this case is that it would include all of the comments for all of the posts, when I only want to load 3 for each post max. That would imply wasting a lot of memory when running this query. if there was a way to apply limit to an eagerly loaded relation that would be the best solution. Something like `@posts = Post.includes(:comments.limit(3)).all` which I know is syntactically incorrect, but demonstrates the idea.

Comment: Yes. i understand you point, can you please check my answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add one new association in post model which will fetch only 3 records of comments

```
has_many :recent_comments, -> { limit(3) }, class_name: 'Comment'
```

and in controller

```
@post = Post.includes(:recent_comments)
```

it won't generate n + 1 query.

Comment: Checking on my console, this seems to trigger the same query as `Post.includes(:comments)`, and so I'm not certain if this is loading all comments or not. Still, I find this to be a great solution. I've submitted an edit since there was a small typo with the class name. Once that's fixed I'll accept the answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Making some tests, this does load all comments, as I can do this:
`@posts = Post.includes(:recent_comments).all` the last post has more than three comments.
`@posts.last.recent_comments` successfully loads three comments
`@posts.last.recent_comments[3]` loads the fourth comment without triggering a query.

I guess the only way to do this would be crafting a custom SQL query?

Comment: I wonder if this solution would rather load just 3 comments only for any number of posts

Comment: @installero Yes it does. Not sure why this answer is accepted

Answer (score 0):

Try to the following

```
@comments = Comment.where('post_id IN (?)', @posts.ids).limit(3)
```

Comment: This would give me the same result as my las failing attempt I wrote on my question. I end up with 3 comments from all my posts. What I need is 3 comments for each post.

This means that I want three comments for post 1, three from post 2 and so on.

Comment: OK, let me check